# Making Django & Vue.js work together with {% verbatim %}

Tags: javascript, django, vuejs2

I'm trying to make django & Vue work together even though they share the same {{ X }} template syntax.

I know that from django 1.5 we can use the `{% verbatim %}` tag. So I thought I could use django templates as usual and in the section where I need VUE to take over I would just use the {% verbatim %} tag. However instead of loading my vue data django loads the `{{ variable }}`.

For example my django code looks something like this:

```
{% verbatim %}

<div id='sessions'>
  <h2>{{message}}</h2>
</div>

{% endverbatim %}
```

And in my app.js file I have:

```
var sessions = new Vue({
  el: '#sessions',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

But instead of rendering `Hello Vue!` it renders `{{message}}`

The console doesn't show any error and vue loads correctly otherwise.

How I can make the two work together? Ideally without the need to change the vue.js {{}} syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change Vue's [interpolation delimiters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters) to whatever you want.

```
var sessions = new Vue({
  el: '#sessions',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

That way you can use whatever your framework needs.

**Edit**

It turned out in this case, @Costantin had more than one div#sessions on the page.

Comment: I tried but I can't seem to get it to work. With your settings I should be able to load the message with `${ message }` right?

Comment: @Costantin You should, yes. Are you getting a console error?

Comment: Because doing that I just get ` ${message}` rendered

Comment: @Costantin Is it possible the template is rendered after the script?

Comment: no console log error. But If I type `sessions.message` I get correctly 
"Hello Vue!"

Comment: @Costantin what is the rendered html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142369/discussion-between-costantin-and-bert-evans).