# VueJs data won't display

Tags: javascript, html, django, templates, vue.js

I use Django and VueJs.

I tried to use Vue in Django template but when try to display data from my script nothing appear.

This is my html file :

```
{% load static %}
<body>
  <p>No polls are available.</p>
  <div id="app">
    {{message}}
  </div>
  <script src="{% static "app.js" %}" defer></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js">     
  </script>
</body>
```

And in my app.js :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

My script is loaded but Hello Vue! won't appear.

Comment: If use Vue, I dont' think it is a good idea to mix-use Django Template. the issue you met should be `{{message}}` is parsed by Django template, {{message}} will be blank if you didn't response with `render_to_response(r'your-template.tpl',{'message': 'something at here'})`, that means when the browser received the response from the server, it doesn't have `{{message}}`at there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Django & Vue.js work together with {% verbatim %}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564875/making-django-vue-js-work-together-with-verbatim)

Answer (score 8):

It seems Vue JS delimiters {{ & }} crashed with jinja template delimiters. The solution is just change the delimiters.

```
new Vue({
    delimiters : ['[[',']]'],
    el: '#app',
    data: () => {
      return {
         message: "hello world"
      }
    }
  })
```

Here I change the delimiters to [[ & ]]. so, you can use it like this :

```
<div id="app">[[message]]</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data

```
data: {
message: 'Hello Vue!'
}
```

Should be

```
 data: function () {
  return {
    messages: 'Hello!'
  }
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, do i need to call the function in an other way ?

Comment: @Max0u that's strange.. Try setting up an example of your code on codepen.io

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in another answer: working example below:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => {
      return {
       message: "hello world"
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Message: {{ message }}
</div>
```