# Index amount isn't printing in Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm sorry i can't give much info because I really don't know why this isn't working, I'm trying to print index but index isn't working at all for some reason, grateful for any help. Index never has any value at any point will always print out none.

HTML PAGE

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<form  method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="con">
      <button type="button" name="button" @click='addHead()'>
          header
      </button>
      <button type="button" name="button" @click='addPara()'>
          Para
      </button>
        <div id="body-fields">
          <div class="car-body" v-for="(post, index) in posts">
            <div name='count'>
              {{index}}
            </div>
            <input type="textbox" v-bind:name='[post.type]' v-model='post.content'>
            <span style="float:right;background-color:green" @click='removeForm(index)'>
                x
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" vaule="save"/>
      </div>
</form>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blog/JS/main.js'%}" type="text/javascript"></script>

  {% endblock content %}
```

Vue.js page

```
var app= new Vue({
  el: '.con',
    data:{
      posts: [
      {
        content:'',
        type:'title'
      }
    ],
    },
    methods:{
      addHead(index){
        this.posts.push({
          content:'',
          type:'header',
        })
      },
      addPara(index){
        this.posts.push({
          content:'',
          type:'para',
        })
      },
      removeForm(){
        this.posts.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the surrounding templating language here? Does that language interpret the `{{index}}` so that it never makes it as far as Vue? If so you may need to change your delimiters: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Comment: I changed it to this delimiters: ['[[', ']]'], however still isnt working now the pgae just displays, "[[index]]"

Comment: Is your JavaScript code definitely running or are you just seeing the `[[index]]` from the template? If you add more entries to `posts` do you see `[[index]]` multiple times?

Comment: yeah I do i've found a workaround which isn't ideal but will do for the time being

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the delimiters (please update your code to show that) to '[[' and ']]', then it will show the  index when using

```
[[index]]
```

To  change the delimters use this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  el: ".con",
```

better yet, address the Vue.js via an ID rather than a class  like

```
var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  el: "#con",
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to fix it ,however comes with it's own issues

```
{% verbatim %}
{{index}}
{% endverbatim %}
```

[Making Django & Vue.js work together with {% verbatim %}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564875/making-django-vue-js-work-together-with-verbatim)

Comment: the {{ }} are Django placeholders